# Get list of longitude and latitude for non-null pixels in a region (Earth Engine)

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, coordinates, pixel

I'm trying to extract the pixel's mid point longitude and latitude value in GEE firms dataset where a fire has occurred. I filtered the image collection  `ee.ImageCollection('FIRMS').filterDate('2020-08-01', '2020-08-06')` and selected only one image from the image collection. Since there were no bands for the longitude and latitude, I used the `reduceRegion()` operation to extract longitude and latitude values in a specific region for the selected image using the below python code.

```
allPixels = image.select('T21').addBands(ee.Image.pixelLonLat()).reduceRegion(
    reducer= ee.Reducer.toList(), 
    geometry = aoi, 
    scale = 1000,
    crs = 'EPSG:4326',
    maxPixels = 1e10
)
```

The above outputs all of the pixel's **T21**, **longitude** and **latitude** values in the region like this.

[image: allpixels]

But **I need to get the mid point longitude and latitude values only where the T21 band value has a non null number**. How can I only get the mid point longitude and latitude value of such pixels?

Comment: The raster data storage model only stores locations the corners (or the centers of the corner pixels, it depends). After that, it's simple interpolation. For any given pixel, it's the corner (possibly less half a pixel width/height), plus or minus the number of pixels from the corner times the pixel size in that dimension. You'd need to provide more specifics to het a more specific answer.

Comment: @Vince thank you for replying, I filtered the image collection like this ee.ImageCollection('FIRMS').filterDate('2020-08-01', '2020-08-06') and selected only one image from the image collection. Then I used this image to perform the reduceRegion() operation. Since the image collection didn't have any bands on longitude and latitude values, I added that using the addBands operation. But the problem I'm having is that, the resulting allPixels dictionary has all of the pixel coordinates, not only the fire pixels. I need to extract only the fire pixel mid coordinates.

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to add information. Comments do not have the formatting capabilities of the Question, and can't be further edited for legibility.

Comment: @Vince As I saw, the reduceRegion() operation gives the corner pixel coordinates, Is there a way to get the center coordinates of the pixels?

Comment: A picture (especially a *clipped* picture) of text output is less useful than the actual text. The difference between a corner and the center is half the pixel size (in each dimension, if not square).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to get the mid point longitude and latitude values **only where the T21 band value has a *non null number***.

Use the 'T21' band mask to mask the lon and lat bands.

```py
fire_pixels = image.select('T21')
lon_lat = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().updateMask(fire_pixels)

allPixels = fire_pixels.addBands(lon_lat).reduceRegion(
    reducer = ee.Reducer.toList(), 
    geometry = aoi, 
    scale = 1000,
    crs = 'EPSG:4326',
    maxPixels = 1e10
)
```

Comment: the above output generates the corner pixel lon/lat values, is there a way to get the midpoint lon/lat value of the pixel?

Comment: See @Vince's 1st comment on your question. If you want more details, ask in a new post.